# Working with a not-stringified object logged to the browser console in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

I have been given a page which logs some object to the console. I want to access this object using getBrowserConsoleMessages(), but unfortunately it appears there as the String "[object Object]" with no way for me to parse it and access its properties.
Or at least no way that is obvious to me.
What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>console.log({message: 'Hello, world!'});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
fixture.page("http://127.0.0.1:5500/test.html")("Check page");

test("Console accessible", async t => {
    const { log } = await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages()
    console.log(JSON.parse(log[0]).message)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The data logged by the 'console.log' function is obtained from the client side as a string, where serialization of the `object` type console messages missing. TestCafe has an issue regarding this: [Improve serialization of browser console message with type 'Object'](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5425).

In the meantime, you can approach the following workarounds:

1. Perform serialization of the `object` variables in the client-side using the `JSON.stringify` method. After that, parse them using the `JSON.parse` method in the test.
2. [Inject Client Scripts](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts.html) into your page and mock the client-side `console.log` function to perform stringify an argument passed to it. For example, create a client script named 'overrideLogs.js' with the code:

```js
var originalConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = data => originalConsoleLog(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Run your tests by TestCafe with the specified client script:

```
testcafe chrome test.js --client-scripts overrideLogs.js
```

After all, output will contain message from the object logged on the page.